# 3 dimensional Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `string` that I am splitting using `string.split(' ');` in order to turn the string into an array.

suppose I have these two tables, `table1` and `table2`.

```
<table border="1" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Image One</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40%;"><img src="airplane.jpg" alt="Image 1"></td>
        <td>
            <dl>
              <dt>airplane</dt>
              <dt>flight</dt>
              <dt>travel</dt>
              <dt>military</dt>
              <dt>word war</dt>
              <dt>GI</dt>
            </dl>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="table2">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Image Two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40%;"><img src="apple.jpg" alt="Image 1"></td>
        <td>
            <dl id="tags">
              <dt>red</dt>
              <dt>apple</dt>
              <dt>round</dt>
              <dt>fruit</dt>
              <dt>healthy</dt>
              <dt>doctor</dt>
            </dl>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

right now for testing purposes I have an id of `tags` on `table2`'s `dl`.

I am using a function to turn that `DL` (#tags) into an array

```
function getArray(id) {
var node, list, arrValue;

    array = [];
    for (node = document.getElementById(id).firstChild;
        node;
        node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == 'DT') {
            array.push(node.innerHTML);
        }
    }
    console.log(array)
}
```

in order to check it against my original `string` to see if any of the values match.
However, I am going to have multiple `DT`'s that the `string` is going to be check against. Would it be correct to add all the tables into a 3d array and then check the values in the `string` against the 3d array? or is there a better approach?

**UPDATE**

The problem is:

I am eventually going to have tables filled with an image and tags. Essentially I want to be able to search those tags against my string (which will be separated into an array) then return the image with the most tags in the string. I am trying to figure out the best way to do that.
Thank you

Comment: This does not look like a good use case for `<table>`s

Comment: What do you mean by "3d array"? Also, please post your whole `dl-to-array` function.

Comment: so to recap: You are creating an array from a string, then you want to compare those array values with values already in a table on the page? Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: I mean 3 dimensional array. I updated question with the full function

Comment: @PatrickGunderson Correct, however, I would prefer not using jquery.

Comment: @Eric: I can not see what you want to do with a 3 dimensional array. Please describe your problem, [not what you think the solution would be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/183280).

Comment: So you have source array `['red', 'sky']` that needs to be checked against arbitrary number of arrays e.g. `['red', 'apple', 'round'], ['airplane', 'flight', 'travel'], ...`? I see a 2d array, not 3d.

Comment: What should happen to the tag `"world war"`? How would it be found? Is it found when the string contains only "world", or does the string need to contain both? Does the order count (i.e. would it be found be "war world", or by "world paradise war")?

Comment: @Bergi World war would be read as 'world' 'war' and order doesnt count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use a three-dimensional array, but only a two-dimensional one with tables and their tags. Or, as Alnitak already mentioned, even better a lookup object:

```
var map = {};
var dls = document.getElementsByTagName('dl');
for (var i = 0, i < dls.length; i++) {
    var tableid = dls[i].id; // identifier?
    var dts = dls[i].getElementsByTagName('dt'); // assuming you don't nest them
    for (var j = 0; j < dts.length; j++) {
        var text = dts[j].textContent || dts[i].innerText;
        var tags = text.split(/\s+/);
        for (var k=0; k<tags.length; k++)
            if (tags[k] in map)
                map[tags[k]].push(tableid);
            else
                map[tags[k]] = [tableid]; // an array
    }
}
/* now, map could look like this:
{
    word: ["table1"],
    war: ["table1"],
    red: ["table2"],
    double: ["table1", "table2"], // tags in more than one table
    …
}
*/
```

To get the table with the most tags in the string you now can use a function like this, which returns the respective tableids sorted by tag occurence:

```
function getHighestTables(string) {
    var tags = string.split(/\s+/);
    var tablecounts = {};
    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        var tables = map[tags[i]] || [];
        for (var j=0; j<tables.length; j++) {
            var tableid = tables[j];
            if (tableid in tablecounts)
                tablecounts[tableid]++;
            else
                tablecounts[tableid] = 1;
        }
    }
/*  tablecounts might now look like this:
    {
        table1: 2
        table2: 5
    }
*/
    return Object.keys(tablecounts).sort(function (a, b) {
        return tablecounts[b] - tablecounts[a];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, how would I use this with my html?

Comment: I moved everythign over to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J4kF9/ if you check the console, I am getting an error

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I fixed the bugs. Updated to http://jsfiddle.net/J4kF9/1/, and the output says that there are more tags from the sentence found in table2 than in table1

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped helped me tremendously

Comment: Just out of curiosity how difficult would it be to edit this function for more than 2 tables

Comment: This does work for an arbitrary amount of tables. For an actual usage of this code, you might need to adapt the selectors and how to get the `tableid` value from it. E.g, in the fiddle I selected the `<table>` elements and used their `id` attribute (instead of selecting the `<dl>` elements as above)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than an array I would use an `Object` to store the list of tags, where the keys are the  tags and the values are irrelevant.

This would give you O(1) lookup to check whether some other string exists in that list, as opposed to an O(n) lookup if you were using `array.indexOf()`.

The function below will find every DT on the page and then return an object containing a map from each DT's text to the ID of its parent DL.

```
function makeMap() {
    var map = {};
    var dls = document.getElementsByTagName('DL');
    for (var i = 0, n = dls.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var dl = dls[i];
        var id = dl.id;
        var node = dl.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == 'DT') {
                var tag = node.textContent || node.innerText; // latter for MSIE
                map[tag] = id;
            }
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Alternatively, in jQuery (with some pure JS mixed in for efficiency):

```
function makeMap2() {
    var map = {};
    var $dt = $('dl > dt');
    $dt.each(function() {
        var tag = this.textContent || this.innerText;
        map[tag] = this.parentNode.id;
    });
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I guess the values should be the table(s) in which the tags are contained, as the OP seems to search for them.

Comment: @Bergi if you like, yes, if each tag can only appear in one table then you could use the values to indicate which one.

Comment: @Alnitak Could you give an example please?

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for the update, however I am still slightly confused on how to implement it. What value do I give to the 'map' parameter? Also, I Would have to call this for every dl? say there are 100+

Comment: @Alnitak how would I view the values?